# Eclipse: Console is running however no window is appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am following a youtube guide and there are no errors in the code however, when I run the program in the console I have 'running' (I put running loop forever to make sure that the game is working) however no window is popping up for the display.
Here is the code

```
    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Dimension;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale = 3;

private Thread thread;
private JFrame frame;
private boolean running = false;

public Game(){
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    frame = new JFrame();
}

public synchronized void start() {
} {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}
public synchronized void stop () {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run(){
    while(running){
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("Go Home");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `game.frame.setVisible(true)` instead of `game.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: `running` is false as you are starting a Thread which calls `run` not `start`

Comment: `run()` method does not include any logic, just a print statement.

Comment: This is a side-note, but you need to make `running` volatile. The `Display` thread doesn't have to see the value change right now. Either that or you need to make a method `synchronized boolean isRunning() { return running; }` which the `Display` thread uses instead of checking `running` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JFrame is the main window that will contain components. It must be set visible. 
On your JFrame object:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's a lesson, don't create an instance of `JFrame` inside your component classes (unless you component class is actually going to use it)

`game.setVisible(true);` is only setting the visibility state of the `Canvas`, not the frame

Instead, make the `JFrame` inside your `main` method instead

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Go Home");
                Game game = new Game();
                frame.setTitle("Go Home");
                frame.add(game);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                game.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, your `start` method is actually empty...

public synchronized void start() {
} /* What's this? */ {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

and the thread is actually been started through the static initialisation of the class, not the method call